# Load dataTable. Successful AJAX request, but no data visible

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, datatable

How do I load json data with serverside processing in a dataTable?

I'm trying to build a custom Wordpress plugin and display results from wpdb inside a dataTable. 
I get a *successful* AJAX return call, but the dataTable only shows a "Processing..." stage and the table does not fill the rows (keeps empty).

Although I have read many(!) similar problems and answers here, any help to load data with ajax and json_encode is much appreciated.
The current code:

dahsboard.php

```
<table id="table-id" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%">
    <thead><tr>
        <th>h_id</th>
        <th>h_subject</th>
    </tr></thead>
```

ajax-grid-data.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
function my_action_callback(){
    global $wpdb;

    $query = "SELECT h_id, h_subject FROM wp_tablename ORDER BY h_id limit 3";
    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results($query);
        foreach ($myrows as $value) {
            $ResultData['h_id'] = $value->h_id;
            $ResultData['h_subject'] = $value->h_subject;
            $data[] = $ResultData;
        }

    $json_data = array(
            "draw"            => 1, 
            "recordsTotal"    => 3,
            "recordsFiltered" => 3, 
            "data"            => $data,
    );

    echo json_encode($json_data);
    die();
}
```

**I think that the problem is in datatype formatting underneath:**

dashbboard.js

```
var oTable;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
    oTable = jQuery('#table-id').DataTable( {
        "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "columnDefs": [{"defaultContent": "-","targets": "_all"}],
        "columns": [
            { "data": "h_id" } ,
            { "data": "h_subject" }
        ],  

        "ajax":{
            url: "admin-ajax.php?action=my_action",
            type: "post",
            dataSrc:'',
            dataType : "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

                //dataSrc: function(data){ return data.data; },
                //async : false,
                //processData: true,
                //accepts: {json: "application/json, text/javascript"},

            success: function(data){
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data)); // successful echo data objects are shown in dashboard.
            },
            error: function(){  
                jQuery("#tablename").append('<tbody class="grid-error"><tr><th colspan="2">No results.</th></tr></tbody>');
                jQuery("#tablename_processing").css("display","none");
            }
        },

    });
});
```

**Current results**

Result php file test: .../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_action

```
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":3,"recordsFiltered":3,"data":[{"h_id":"37168","h_subject":"6216"},{"h_id":"37169","h_subject":"7021"},{"h_id":"37170","h_subject":"8923"}]}
```

Result ajax success function, console data:

```
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":3,"recordsFiltered":3,"data":[{"h_id":"37168","h_subject":"6216"},{"h_id":"37169","h_subject":"7021"},{"h_id":"37170","h_subject":"8923"}]}
```

Result dashboard table only shows: `processing...`

Comment: in ajax-grid-data.php change in `$json_data` change `"draw" => 1` to `"draw" => $_GET['draw']`

Comment: The console.log shows me that $_GET['draw'] returns null.

Comment: Using intval($_GET['draw']), gives me "draw":0,

Comment: remove the `success` option and change `dataSrc` from the empty string to a `function(data){return data;}` like in this example https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Comment: @bassxzero is close, you should not change the `dataSrc` property, you should remove it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the `dataSrc` and `success function` did wonders and fills up the dataTable with data. I really appreciate the help and efforts of **@bassxzero** and **@davidkonrad**.

Ensuring that there is an answer, "on behalf of" the new version of dashboard.js:

```
var oTable;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery.fn.dataTable.ext.errMode = 'throw';
oTable = jQuery('#table-id').DataTable( {
    "serverSide": true,
    "processing": true,
    "columnDefs": [{"defaultContent": "-","targets": "_all"}],
    "columns": [
        { "data": "h_id" } ,
        { "data": "h_subject" }
    ],  

    "ajax":{
        url: "admin-ajax.php?action=my_action",
        type: "post",
        dataType : "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        error: function(){  
            jQuery("#tablename").append('<tbody class="grid-error"><tr><th colspan="2">No results.</th></tr></tbody>');
            jQuery("#tablename_processing").css("display","none");
        }
    },

});
```

});